# Joining similar sections from configparser

Tags: python, python-3.x, ini

Good morning,

I have a configuration file with data like this:

```
[hostset 1]
ip = 192.168.122.136
user = test
password =
pkey = ~/.ssh/id_rsa

[hostset 2]
ip = 192.168.122.138
user = test
password =
pkey = ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I want to be able to join the ips of any given number of host sets in this configuration file if the other values are the same, so the ingested and formatted data would be stored in a dict, something like this:

```py
{
 ip: ['192.168.122.136', '192.168.122.138'],
 user: 'test',
 password: '',
 pkey: '~/.ssh/id_rsa',
}
```

by doing something like:

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser


def unpack(d):
    return [value for key, value in d.items()]


def parse(configuration_file):
    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.read(configuration_file)

    hosts = [unpack(connection) for connection in [section for section in dict(parser).values()]][1:]

    return [i for i in hosts]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse('config.ini')
```

I can get a list of lists containing the elements of the configuration file, like this:

```py
[['192.168.122.136', 'test', '', '~/.ssh/id_rsa'], ['192.168.122.138', 'test', '', '~/.ssh/id_rsa']]
```

Then I just need a way of comparing the two lists and if all elements are similar except for the ip, then join them into a list like:

```py
[['192.168.122.136','192.168.122.138'], 'test', '', '~/.ssh/id_rsa']
```

So I would just need a smart way of doing this with a list of lists of no specific length and join all similar lists.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you using `configparser` for that?

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using configparser to read the .ini file:
```python
from configparser import ConfigParser

parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read('config.ini')
```
if we look at it with dict() it will return something like this:

```python
{'DEFAULT': <Section: DEFAULT>, 'hostset 1': <Section: hostset 1>, 'hostset 2': <Section: hostset 2>}
```

Comment: The issue is how to smartly iterate over all of the sections to check for matching user/key/pass then join those sections by the ip.

Answer (score 1):

Got some help from a friend and solved the question. The key was making the values I wanted to compare into a tuple, making that tuple the key to a dictionary and the value the ips. From this. I can assert that if the tuple key already exists, then I will append the ip to the value.

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser
from ast import literal_eval as literal


def unpack(d):
    return [value for key, value in d.items()]


def parse(configuration_file):
    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.read(configuration_file)

    hosts = [unpack(connection) for connection in [section for section in dict(parser).values()]][1:]

    d = dict()
    for item in hosts:
        try:
            d[str((item[1:]))].append(item[0])
        except KeyError:
            d[str((item[1:]))] = [item[0]]

    return d


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for k, v in parse('config.ini').items():
        print([v, *literal(k)])
```

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, I presumed that the file format is exactly as described in the question:
First we split the host sets:
we suppose that your data is in rowdata variable

```
HostSets = rowdata.split("[hostset ") # first element is empty
Dict = {}

for i in range (1,len(HostSets)):
    l = HostSets[i].split("ip = ")#two elements the first is trash
    ip = l[1].split()[0]
    conf =l[1].split("\n",1 )[1] #splits only the first element 
    try :
        Dict[conf].append(ip)
    except :
        Dict[conf] = list()
        Dict[conf].append(ip)        
print('{')
for element in Dict:
    print("ip: ",Dict[element],",",element)
print('}')
```

Comment: I just edited my question to make it more clear what I am asking.